# sampling from the product of two conditional distributions

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability

Assume x,y,z are dependent variables.

I want to sample z from p(z|x,y) but direct sampling is impossible.

Instead, I can sample z from p(z|x) and p(z|y) independently. But I would like to sample z using all information (x,y) I have.

If I sample z from:

$z \sim \dfrac{p(z|x)p(z|y)}{\int_{z'} p(z'|x)p(z'|y)dz'}$

would this sampling be a reasonable approximation compared to $z \sim p(z|x,y)$ ?

If it is practical usage, could you give me an example?

Or is there better way to sample z from p(z|x,y) given above assumptions?

**EDIT**

I also considered $$z \sim \frac{1}{2}[p(z|x)+p(z|y)]$$, when sampling (and evaluation) from $z \sim p(z|x,y)$  is not available.

So I'm trying to show that $z \sim \frac{1}{2}[p(z|x)+p(z|y)]$ is better than $z \sim p(z|x)$ or $z \sim p(z|y)$ by showing KL divergence is smaller:

$$ KL\left(p(z|x,y) \middle\| \frac{1}{2}[p(z|x)+p(z|y)]\right) < KL\left(p(z|x,y) \middle\| p(z|x)\right) $$

$$\int{p(z|x,y)\log{\frac{p(z|x,y)}{\frac{1}{2}[p(z|x)+p(z|y)]}}}dz < \int{p(z|x,y)\log{\frac{p(z|x,y)}{p(z|x)}}}dz$$
-->
$$-\int{p(z|x,y)\log{p(z|x)}}dz + \int{p(z|x,y)\log\left({\frac{1}{2}[p(z|x)+p(z|y)]}\right)}dz > 0$$

From above inequality, I've noticed that if the support of p(z|x) cannot cover p(z|x,y), the first term goes to infinity, while second term uses p(z|y) to make the support wider and possibly cover p(z|x,y), resulting inequality is validated.

In the case where p(z|x) cannot cover p(z|x,y), $\frac{1}{2}[p(z|x)+p(z|y)]$ which uses x,y information looks better approach.

Could this reasoning be sufficient to use $\frac{1}{2}[p(z|x)+p(z|y)]$ other than p(z|x) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:
$$p(z|x,y)\ne p(z|x)p(z|y)\Big/ \int p(z|x)p(z|y)\,\text dz$$
in general. The fundamental reason is that the marginal conditionals $p(z|x)$ and $p(z|y)$ do not incorporate any information about the joint distribution of $(x,y)$.

To wit,
$$p(z|x,y)=\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(x,y)}=\frac{p(x,z)p(y|x,z)}{p(x,y)}$$
while
$$p(z|x)p(z|y) = \dfrac{p(x,z)p(y,z)}{p(x)p(y)}$$
For instance, it can happen that $$\int p(x,z)p(y,z)\,\text d z=+\infty$$
Another illustration of the difference is that, when $p(z|x)=p(z|y)=p(z|x,y)$ (as when $x$ and $y$ are in bijection),$$p(z|x)p(z|y)=p(z|x,y)^2$$
which is not proportional to $p(z|x,y)$ and usually more concentrated / less variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would it be reasonable to sample z from (|)(|) for using (x,y) information, even if it is different from (|,) ?

Comment: Not in general, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So marginal conditions are different from the joint distribution of (x,y). I've come up with other sampling strategy to use both x,y information, described in my question EDIT. Could you please check and give me some advice?